# Making button text be the output of a function after each click

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have an idea where I have a function that randomizes greetings in different languages. Originally, I just wanted to have the greeting at the top of the page change after each refresh to a random greeting, but I am trying to make it so when you click the text created from the function, it is a button that runs the function again and the new output becomes the button label which you can keep clicking to get a new value (new button label).

```
<head>
  <script class="astext" id="doSmth">
    //Random greeting script
    function greetingbutton() {

        var greetings = ["Ciao!", "Hola!", "Howdy Partner!", "こんにちは！", "Take me to your leader!", "Bonjour!", "Здравствуйте!", "السلام عليكم"];

        var random_greet = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

        var leader = greetings[random_greet];

        var buto = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = leader;

    }

</script>
<style>
    .astext {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="container h1 text-center">
    <button onclick="greetingbutton()" class="astext" id="doSmth">
    <script>
       document.write(buto);
        </script>
    </button>
    <h1 id="button"></h1>

</div>
```

This is meant to be a sort of Easter egg, explaining the class="astext".

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you post to jsbin to have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: You just need to call the function after creating.

Comment: this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/a6ds0cy4/

Comment: What Josan suggested fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, add the following statement after the `greetingbutton()` definition:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    greetingbutton();
});
```

Or just add a call to the function instead:

```
greetingbutton();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
$('.astext').on('click',function() {
   var $btn = $(this);
   var greetings = ["Ciao!", "Hola!", "Howdy Partner!", "こんにちは！", "Take me to your leader!", "Bonjour!", "Здравствуйте!", "السلام عليكم"];

    var random_greet = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

    var leader = greetings[random_greet];
    $btn.html(leader);
});
```

and your HTML will be just:

```
<div class="container h1 text-center">
    <button class="astext" id="doSmth">/button>
    <h1 id="button"></h1>
</div>
```